# Following official tutorial for i18n integration with JIT compiler, website is still in english

Tags: angular

I am following the guide here https://angular.io/guide/i18n to set up my app for i18n using the JIT compiler. I have successfully generated my translation files in french, as the tutorial says. However, when I run the app, my page is still in english. No errors are outputted in the console.

I'm not sure if it's my translation file that is off- is there a way to see that my translation file is not being integrated with my app correctly? When I deliberately mess up the format of the translation file, no errors are outputted still.

My main.ts is edited to include:

```
const translations = require(raw-loader!../i18n/messages.fr.xlf);

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
    providers: [
        {provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations},
        {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf'},
        {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue:'fr'}
    ]
});
```

And my translation file essentially looks like:

```
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="uniqueID" datatype="html">
        <source> Hello </source>
         <target>Bonjour</target>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">app/app.component.ts</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">5</context>
        </context-group>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

Comment: What about the `app.module.ts` ? Did you provide the LOCALE_ID in the main module ?

Comment: Yes, I added that as well.